# How to swap array's columns if condition is satisfied

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I have an `Nx3` numpy array:

```
A = [[01,02,03]
     [11,12,13]
     [21,22,23]]
```

I need an array where the second and third columns are swapped if the sum of the second and third numbers is greater then 20:

```
[[01,02,03]
 [11,13,12]
 [21,23,22]]
```

Is it possible to achieve this without a loop?

**UPDATE:**

So, the story behind this is that I want to swap colors in a RGB image, namely green and blue, but not yellow - this is my condition. Empirically I found out it is `abs(green - blue) > 15 && (blue > green)`

```
swapped = np.array(img).reshape(img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2])
idx = ((np.abs(swapped[:,1] - swapped[:,2]) < 15) & (swapped[:, 2] < swapped[:, 1]))

swapped[idx, 1], swapped[idx, 2] = swapped[idx, 2], swapped[idx, 1]

plt.imshow(swapped.reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2]))
```

this actually works, but partially. The first column will be swapped, but the second one will be overwritten.

```
# tested in pyton3
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23]])
a[:,1], a[:,2] = a[:,2], a[:,1]

array([[ 1,  3,  3],
       [11, 13, 13],
       [21, 23, 23]])
```

Comment: Post the code that you have tried to use to solve this problem.

Comment: Also what would be your expected output?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way with `masking` -

```
# Get 1D mask of length same as the column length of array and with True
# values at places where the combined sum is > 20
m = A[:,1] + A[:,2] > 20

# Get the masked elements off the second column
tmp = A[m,2]

# Assign into the masked places in the third col from the
# corresponding masked places in second col.
# Note that this won't change `tmp` because `tmp` isn't a view into
# the third col, but holds a separate memory space
A[m,2] = A[m,1]

# Finally assign into the second col from tmp
A[m,1] = tmp
```

Sample run -

```
In [538]: A
Out[538]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [21, 22, 23]])

In [539]: m = A[:,1] + A[:,2] > 20
     ...: tmp = A[m,2]
     ...: A[m,2] = A[m,1]
     ...: A[m,1] = tmp

In [540]: A
Out[540]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [11, 13, 12],
       [21, 23, 22]])
```

Comment: `A[m,2], A[m, 1] = A[m, 1], A[m,2]`?

Comment: No, I was just giving you a little alternative to your code, which uses a temp variable to swap :) (since in python, you can swap without a temp variable).

Comment: Actually I tried this alternative and it didn't do the job. Check my update.

Comment: @Aray What about the `masking` based one? Did you try that one?

Comment: @Divakar this one: A[m,2], A[m, 1] = A[m, 1], A[m,2]

Comment: @Aray No, try `masking` one using `tmp`.

Comment: @Divakar I already tried. This was my first solution. I was hoping there was a better one. Check my update.

Comment: @Aray I don't see use of any `tmp` variable in your update.

Comment: I removed it from my code, because you already posted it and that's why I gave you +1 :)

Comment: @Aray So, did it work with `mask` + `tmp` variable one for you?

Comment: @Aray That `A[m,2], A[m, 1] = A[m, 1], A[m,2]` probably has latency issue and hence won't work. I don't see the point of listing that approach in your question. It will only confuse readers. I would suggest removing the UPDATE part that includes that code snippet.

Comment: @Divakar Do you mean the last code snippet or the whole update?

Comment: I found a bug in your solution. You should do a copy of the `A[m,2]`, otherwise you assign a reference to the `tmp` which will be overwritten

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.

Comment: @Divakar to me, your answer looks perfectly fine! I don't know what's wrong with the above commenter :(

Comment: @Aray No, it's perfectly fine. Added comments to make it clear.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I have updated the post. Maybe it wasn't a great answer, but it wasn't a bad/not-helpful one worthy of a downvote. We clearly have different standards.

Comment: @kmario23 Yeah, just people having different standards of voting, is all.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, if someone doesn't like the answer, then he/she should leave a constructive comment mentioning the flaws, if at all there is a flaw.

Comment: @Divakar my answer works. But, it seems little uglier. Any suggestions to make it less clumsy?

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) along with "fancy" indexing, and [`np.flip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) to swap the elements.

```
In [145]: A
Out[145]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [21, 22, 23]])

# extract matching sub-array
In [146]: matches = A[np.where(np.sum(A[:, 1:], axis=1) > 20)]

In [147]: matches
Out[147]: 
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [21, 22, 23]])

# swap elements and update the original array using "boolean" indexing
In [148]: A[np.where(np.sum(A[:, 1:], axis=1) > 20)] = np.hstack((matches[:, :1], np.flip(matches[:, 1:], axis=1)))

In [149]: A
Out[149]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [11, 13, 12],
       [21, 23, 22]])
```

---

One more approach based on [@Divakar's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233402/how-to-swap-arrays-columns-if-condition-is-satisfied/48242519#comment83477165_48242519) would be to:

First get the indices which are nonzero for the condition specified (here 
 sum of the elements in second and third column > 20)

```
In [70]: idx = np.flatnonzero(np.sum(A[:, 1:3], axis=1) > 20)
```

Then create an open mesh using `np.ix_`

```
In [71]: gidx = np.ix_(idx,[1,2])

# finally update the original array `A`
In [72]: A[gidx] = A[gidx][:,::-1]
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.

Comment: How about : `idx = np.flatnonzero(np.sum(A[:, 1:3], axis=1) > 20); gidx = np.ix_(idx,[1,2]) ; A[gidx] = A[gidx][:,::-1]`?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I updated the post with more explanation. Again, it might not be a top-notch answer but still correct answer. IMO, working solutions should not qualify for a downvote or a delete vote.